# PNG images are not uploaded correctly when I publish pipeline artifact in Azure DevOps

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, png, azure-artifacts

Build docker image from azure devops pipeline and when I deploy the application, the PNG images are not displaying. To cross check, I just published pipeline artifact to check the PNG image files. The image is available but it shows `windows photo viewer can’t display this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large` when I download and open the file

`Azure-devops-pipeline.yaml`

```
trigger:
- none

stages:
- stage: PublishBuildArtifacts
  displayName: PublishBuildArtifacts
  jobs:
  - job: Publish
    displayName: PublishBuildArtifacts
    pool:
      vmimage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test png'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

How to get upload PNG images correctly when I use Azure DevOps pipeline because when I build the Docker image locally, the image works as expected for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related "Encountered 1 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't"

Updated the Image by GUI instead of VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a hint : *.artifactignore*

is there a missing '.' in *PathtoPublish* value ?

Comment: I noticed that, in my repository, `.gitattributes` contains `*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text`. This might be the reason and I see an error when I clone my repository `"Encountered 1 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't"` because I have uploaded the PNG image directly from Azure DevOps UI, not through git.